# TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed on Accordion panels

Tags: actionscript-3

i use an ready Accordion Panel in Flash ( here )

now when i add any button on this frame i get this error when i click Accordion tabs :

> TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert
>   flash.display::SimpleButton@48596ab9 to flash.display.MovieClip.

and when i add movieclip to the stage i get this error right after click on any Accordion panels :

> TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
>   at mobver2_fla::MainTimeline/onClick()

here is the main script for Accordion panel :

```
import gs.*;    
import gs.easing.*;

panel1.props = {ly:53, ry:650, ind:1};    
panel2.props = {ly:115, ry:700, ind:2};    
panel3.props = {ly:169, ry:750, ind:3};

panel1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);    
panel2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);    
panel3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void    
{    
    var clicked:MovieClip = MovieClip(e.target);

    for(var i:int=0; i<numChildren; i++)    
    {    
        var mc:MovieClip = MovieClip(getChildAt(i));

        if(mc.props.ind <= clicked.props.ind)    
            TweenLite.to(mc, 1, {y:mc.props.ly, ease:Bounce.easeOut});    
        else    
            TweenLite.to(mc, 1, {y:mc.props.ry, ease:Bounce.easeOut});    
    }    
}
```

it seems this script effect on all movieclip or buttons in Frame , but i cant figure it out how i must separate other buttons and movieclips from this . i really need to add some button and movie clip to these panels and frame

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all - you try to cast a button to a MovieClip, and SimpleButton is **NOT** a MovieClip.

This has nothing to do with the Accordion.

You need to change this line:

```
var clicked:MovieClip = MovieClip(e.target);
```

Start using debugger and traces to see what are you actually doing. Also - **enable permit debugging** to see on which line the error is.

We cannot help you every time you do something wrong, as this is not a common problem, nor pattern oriented, it's just a simple error of yours.

Comment: Dear Andrey popov please don`t be Offensive with me .

common problems are solve by search in google and not need to ask !!

believe me i try it by myself and after no success comes here and ask it .

i dont know how to change MovieClip(e.target) to define three movie clips with instance names : panel1 , panel2 , panel3

Comment: Sorry for the words, but this is not a common **problem**, this is common **lack of knowledge**. Which is fine, but the way of gaining knowledge is not by asking someone to fix it instead of you, but trying to fix it yourself instead. Search Google for what that error means, check why it's thrown.. Don't just ask every time you get an error!